# Xamarin Forms SfDataGrid Custom Mapping

Tags: xamarin.forms, datagridview, syncfusion

I am developing an application using xamarin forms with syncfusion. I couldn't create a solution for the json file below.

The page consists of 3 columns and takes these column headers from the **label** field. (this is the same for all properties)

it takes the content from the **display** area.

I can't do normal mapping here. A different perspective is required.

I will be glad if you help me. Thank you.

```
    {
    "serviceItems": [
        {
            "id": "79471",
            "ref": "7",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "label": "Text Field",
                    "display": "sample text",
                    "value": "sample text",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "objectType": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Datetime Field",
                    "display": "19.03.2020 12:14:00",
                    "value": "3/19/2020 12:14:00 PM",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "datetime",
                    "objectType": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Date Field",
                    "display": "19.03.2020",
                    "value": "3/19/2020 12:00:00 AM",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "date",
                    "objectType": 0
                }
            ],
            "swipeItems": [
                {
                    "type": "action",
                    "icon": "approve",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": {
                        "eventId": "5",
                        "eventText": "Onayla",
                        "reasonRequired": "false",
                        "showHistory": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "action",
                    "icon": "reject",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": {
                        "eventId": "6",
                        "eventText": "Reddet",
                        "reasonRequired": "true",
                        "showHistory": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "delete",
                    "icon": "delete",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": null
                }
            ],
            "leftSideIcon": "green",
            "rightSideIcon": "attachment",
            "abortHistory": false
        },
        {
            "id": "79597",
            "ref": "7",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "label": "Text Field",
                    "display": "sample text",
                    "value": "sample text",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "objectType": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Date Field",
                    "display": "26.03.2020 19:00:36",
                    "value": "3/26/2020 7:00:36 PM",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "datetime",
                    "objectType": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "Datetime Field",
                    "display": "26.03.2020 19:00:36",
                    "value": "3/26/2020 7:00:36 PM",
                    "accessibility": {
                        "visible": false,
                        "editable": false,
                        "required": false
                    },
                    "dataType": "date",
                    "objectType": 0
                }
            ],
            "swipeItems": [
                {
                    "type": "action",
                    "icon": "reject",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": {
                        "eventId": "6",
                        "eventText": "Reddet",
                        "reasonRequired": "true",
                        "showHistory": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "edit",
                    "icon": "edit",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": null
                },
                {
                    "type": "action",
                    "icon": "approve",
                    "url": null,
                    "event": {
                        "eventId": "5",
                        "eventText": "Onayla",
                        "reasonRequired": "false",
                        "showHistory": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "leftSideIcon": "red",
            "rightSideIcon": "attachment",
            "abortHistory": false
        }
    ],
}
```

[image: Want To Screen]

Answer (score 0):

We would like to tell, that’s not a proper way to populate the JSON data with SfDataGrid. Since you have initialized Value for all the three properties. So, the text is taken from the Value field. We have already published a KB to populate the JSON data with SfDataGrid.

KB link : https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7828/how-to-load-sfdatagrid-dynamically-with-json-data-without-poco-classes

Regards,
Karthik Raja